# MYSQL: only return column names where rows are empty

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I just want to know how to receive ALL column names which contain empty rows (not empty tables itself)

They all have some rows, but they're not filled with any data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get empty rows by

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1='' AND column2=''
```

If "" is what you meant by empty row

Comment: i cannot use this within mysql itself, right? i'm just looking for a command that i can use as a query within phpmyadmin for example.

Comment: @Thyrador, no, the query you are looking for then is `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(SomeColumn,''), ReplacementColumn)
FROM SomeTable
```

You can extends that to 3 columns too:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Address2,''), NULLIF(Address3,''), Address4)
```

Comment: i'm just looking for a command without entering a column name, because there are thousands of columns matching the criteria. what i want is a list, that throws out all the column names, matching the criteria.